# Thumbnail photo in messaging app

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7

I just upgraded from a Galaxy S5 to a Galaxy S7 (verizon) and my thunbnail photo no longer shows up when i send a text message.  When someone sends me a message, thier photo shows up, but there isnt even a blank head for my photo.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the Contacts app, you should have a Contact for you under the heading *My Profile*.  That's where you'll have to setup a photo and any other info there you wish to add.  It should be right at the top of the list.

Comment: yeah.  i just realized that when i send a text, my thumbnail shows up to the person i'm sending it to.  I'm just not seeing it, like i used to on the S5.  thats fine.  i dont need to see myself!